# Find $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt [3] {3},\sqrt [3] {2}):\mathbb{Q}]$

Tags: field-theory, extension-field

I am trying to find $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt [3] {3},\sqrt [3] {2}):\mathbb{Q}]$. My guess is it is $9$. There are 3 possibilities-3,6,9. If it is not 9 then $X^{3}-3$ is not irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt [3] {2})$ hence it has a root in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt [3] {2})$. But $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt [3] {2})$ is real field so the only possibility is that it contains $\sqrt [3] {3}$. To show this is not the case I assumed that $\sqrt [3] {3}=a+b\sqrt [3] {2}+c\sqrt [3] {4}$ and cubed both side. I have not yet completed it , but seems this methode is very long. Is there a better approach?

I WANT A SOLUTION WHICH DOES NOT USE ANY GALOIS THEORY/ALGEBRAIC NUMBER THEORY.

Comment: Hint: Find a primitive element which generates $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt [3] {3},\sqrt [3] {2})$.

Comment: This question is shown in the list of related questions on the right: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/367013/prove-sqrt33-notin-mathbbq-sqrt32

Comment: I want some elementary solution (using basic field theory) , not using any Galois theory/algebraic number theory.

Comment: Note that your edit automatically put the post in the [reopen review queue](http://math.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/268478). You can also ask for reopening [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6424/requests-for-reopen-undeletion-votes-etc). (If you post your request in that thread, you should explain the reason why the post should be reopened.)

Comment: BTW $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt [3] {3},\sqrt [3] {2}):\mathbb{Q}]=[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt [3] {3},\sqrt [3] {2}):\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]2)] \cdot [\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt [3] {2}):\mathbb{Q}]$ implies that the possibilities are 3 and 9.