# Proving $\sqrt[3]{5} \notin \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$ with solvability of system in $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field

We were asked to show that $\sqrt[3]{5} \notin \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$ by reducing the problem to the solvability of system in $\mathbb{Q}$. There was also a hint with it that a system does not need to be linear. I don't really know what exactly they're expecting. Intuitively I would start by $\sqrt[3]{5} \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$ such that $\sqrt[3]{5}= a + b\sqrt[3]{2} + c\sqrt[3]{4}$ for some $a,b,c \in \mathbb{Q}$ and try searching for a contradiction as I have seen in similar posts on this sort of problems. However when I cube it, it gets quite large and I get lost in the calculation. The answers on other posts on this all use concepts we haven't seen yet so I assume there is another way to solve this using the hint.

Comment: You could also some how show that the equation $x^3=5$ does not have a solution in $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3] 2)$... I am not sure if there's a straight forward way to show this either...

Comment: Do you have links to the other similar posts that use concepts you haven't  seen yet?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2431221/why-sqrt33-not-in-mathbbq-sqrt32 this is one. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/367013/prove-sqrt33-notin-mathbbq-sqrt32?noredirect=1&lq=1 this is another

Comment: Concepts such as trace, Galois group, discriminant of a field are all concepts we haven't explicitly seen yet.

Answer (score 3):

The cube is not that bad, and that is surely what you are expected to do if they tell you to "reduce to a system over $\mathbb{Q}$." You just need to do the algebra carefully.

**(Corrected)**

Use the formula
$$(x+y+z)^3 = x^3+y^3 + z^3 + 3x^2y+3x^2z +  3xy^2 + 3y^2z + 3xz^2 + 3yz^2 + 6xyz.$$
We have:
$$\begin{align*}
(a+b2^{1/3}+c2^{2/3})^3 &= a^3 + 2b^3 + 4c^4\\
&\qquad+ 3a^2b2^{1/3} + 3a^2c2^{2/3} + 3ab^22^{2/3} + 6b^2c2^{1/3}\\
&\qquad + 6ac^22^{1/3} + 6bc^22^{2/3} + 12abc\\
&= \bigl( a^3+2b^3+4c^3+12abc\bigr)\\
&\qquad + \bigl(3a^2b + 6b^2c + 6ac^2)2^{1/3}\\
&\qquad + \bigl(3a^2c + 3ab^2 + 6bc^2)2^{2/3}
\end{align*}$$
For $a+b2^{1/3}+c2^{2/3}$ to equal $\sqrt[3]{5}$, you need this to equal $5$, so you have the system
$$\begin{align*}
a^3+2b^3+4c^3+12abc &=5\\
3a^2b+6b^2c+6ac^2 &= 0\\
3a^2c+3ab^2+6bc^2 &=0
\end{align*}$$
We can divide the last two equations by $3$ to get
$$\begin{align*}
a^3+2b^3+4c^3+12abc &=5\\
a^2b+2b^2c+2ac^2 &= 0\\
a^2c+ab^2+2bc^2 &=0
\end{align*}$$
If any of $a$, $b$, or $c$ are zero, then the second or third equation give that at least two of them are zero. Then the first equation would ask us to solve $a^3=5$, $2b^3=5$, or $4c^3=5$ in rational numbers, which is impossible. Thus, all of $a,b,c$ would necessarily be nonzero. So we may assume they are all nonzero.

Rewrite the last equation as
$$a(ac + b^2) + 2bc^2 = 0,$$
which gives $(ac+b^2) = -\frac{2bc^2}{a}$.
Now rewrite the second equation as
$$a^2b+2c(b^2+ac) = 0,$$
so plugging in the value of $ac+b^2$ we get:
$$\begin{align*}
a^2b+2c(b^2+ac) &=0\\
a^2b + 2c\left(-\frac{2bc^2}{a}\right) &= 0\\
a^2b - \frac{4bc^3}{a} &= 0\\
a^3b - 4bc^3 &=0\\
b(a^3-4c^3)&=0\\
a^3-4c^3 &=0\\
a^3 &= 4c^3.
\end{align*}$$
This is impossible for rationals $a$ and $c$: the power of $2$ that appears on the left is a multiple of $3$ (positive or negative). But the power of $2$ that appears on the right hand side is of the form $3m+2$, with $m$ an integer.

Thus, there are no solutions to this system in rationals, hence $\sqrt[3]{5}$ is not an element of $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[3]{2}]$.

Comment: are you sure about the calculations of the cube? Since I reach this system: $ \begin{align*}
a^3+2b^3+4c^3+12abc &=5\\
3a^2b+6b^2c+6ac^2 &= 0\\
3a^2c+3ab^2 +6bc^2&=0
\end{align*}$

Comment: @rikdb I did not double-check. I'll do that later today. But I think you may be right about the $bc^2$ term.

Comment: If I'm right about the cube, how would I go about proving the objective.

Comment: Because I don't see an immediate similar way

Comment: @rikdb Sorry about that; and I was busy the last couple of days. I believe this fixes it, and the analysis of the system is not that hard.

Answer (score 1):

If you keep your calm and do algebra, it all works out.

Let us write
$$\sqrt[3]{5} = a + b\sqrt[3]{2} + c\sqrt[3]{4}.$$

Squaring,
$$\sqrt[3]{25} = (a^2 + 4bc) + (2c^2+2ab)\sqrt[3]{2} + (b^2+2ac)\sqrt[3]{4}.$$

Thus
$$5 = (a^3+4abc+2b^3+4abc+4c^3+4abc) + (2ac^2+2a^2b+2b^2c+4ac^2)\sqrt[3]{2} + (ab^2+2a^2c+2bc^2+2ab^2)\sqrt[3]{4}.$$

This in turn reduces to the system
$$2a^2c+2bc^2+3ab^2 = 0,$$
$$2a^2b+2b^2c+6ac^2=0,$$
$$a^3+2b^3+4c^3+12abc=5$$
over the rationals. We wish to explain why this has no solutions.

Let us first pick the smallest integer $N$ so that each of $aN, bN, cN$ is an integer. Write these as $A=aN, B = bN, C = cN$ and multiply each equation by $N^3$ to find
$$2A^2C+2BC^2+3AB^2=0,$$
$$A^2B+B^2C+3AC^2=0,$$
$$A^3+2B^3+4C^3+12ABC=5N^3.$$

If $N$ is odd, then we get a contradiction as follows.

From the last equation, we can deduce that $A$ is odd. From the first equation, we then deduce that $B$ is even. The quantity $A^2B+B^2C$ is then even, and so from the second equation we deduce that $3AC^2$ is even. This As $A$ is odd, we find that $C$ is even. Say that $B = 2^xB', C = 2^yC'$ where $B', C'$ are odd. Then our second equation can be rewritten
$$2^xA^2B'+2^{2x+y}(B')^2(C') + 3\cdot 2^{2y}A(C')^2 = 0.$$

If $2y > x,$ then we could divide by $2^x$ to get a contradiction that a sum of an odd number plus two even numbers is even. Thus we must have $x \geq 2y.$ The first equation reads
$$2^{y+1}A^2C' + 2^{x+2y+1}(B')(C')^2 + 3\cdot 2^{2x}A(B')^2 = 0.$$

If $y+1 < 2x,$ we could divide by it and get a similar contradiction to before, so we now know $y+1\geq 2x.$ But we also know $x\geq 2y.$ Both of these inequalities at once are bad for positive integers $x,y$: note that
$$y+1 \geq 2x \geq 2(2y) = 4y,$$
but $y$ needs to be a positive integer and no positive integer obeys $y+1 \geq 4y.$ Thus there are no solutions.

--

Therefore $N$ is even. But if $N$ is even, then our last equation implies $A$ is even. If $B$ and $C$ were both even, then we could divide $N$ by 2 to get a smaller $N$ while still clearing denominators, contradicting its minimality; if $B, C$ were both odd, then our second equation would find a contradiction, as the outer two terms (multiples of $A$) would be even but the middle term $B^2C$ would be odd, yet they sum to the even number zero. Hence one of $B,C$ is even and the other is odd.

Take our last equation modulo $8.$ The terms $A^3$ and $5N^3$ both become zero, since $A, N$ are even and $2^3 = 8.$ The term $12ABC$ is also 0, since $12$ gives a factor of 4 and then $A$ gives another factor of $2.$

Thus the equation becomes $8 \mid (2B^3+4C^3)$ after reducing modulo 8. But this is impossible: if $C$ is the even one of $B,C,$ then $4C%3$ is a multiple of $8$ and so $8 \mid 2B^3,$ absurd since $B$ odd; the same problem happens if $B$ is the even one, and we conclude.

Comment: When you write "we can deduce that $A$ is odd", you are probably assuming that you choose $N$ to be minimal, for I believe in that case you can do some kind of reduction argument by showing that if $N$ were even, then $A$, $B$ and $C$ must all be even too so you can divide out some shared factors of $2$

Comment: @MikeDaas Thanks for catching -- at the end of my answer I now address why we can take $N$ odd.

Comment: I’m not sure whether the system you calculated is correct. It should have factor 3 and 6 in the zero terms from my calculations.

Comment: Your computations of the system are not correct. For example, the coefficient of $\sqrt[3]{2}$ you have obtained is the result of multiplying the $a$ from $\sqrt[3]{5}$ with the $(2c^2+2ab)\sqrt[3]{2}$ of $\sqrt[3]{25}$, and adding the result of multiplying $c\sqrt[3]{4}$ with $(b^2+2ac)\sqrt[3]{4}$. But you are missing the product of $b\sqrt[3]{2}$ with $(a^2+4bc)$. Likewise, the $\sqrt[3]{4}$ term is missing the result of multiplying $c\sqrt[3]{4}$ with $(a^2+4bc)$.