# Show that $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2},\sqrt[3]{3}):\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})] \gt1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

I have to show that the degree $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2},\sqrt[3]{3}):\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})]$ is $\gt1$.

I know that for this purpose it is enought to show that $\sqrt[3]{3} \notin \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$, but how can I show this?

Comment: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level

Comment: Also, a dupe of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/367013/11619) or [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/55515/11619).

Answer (score 4):

You can use traces.

Suppose that $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]2)=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]3)$, and write 
$$
\sqrt[3]3= a+b\sqrt[3]2+c\sqrt[3]4, $$
with $a,b,c\in\mathbb{Q}$.

Using the idea in a [note](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/gradnumthy/Qw2.pdf) by K. Conrad, we have
$$0 = Tr_Q^K \sqrt[3]3 = Tr_Q^K (a+b\sqrt[3]2+c\sqrt[3]4)= 3a,$$
$$0 = Tr_Q^K \sqrt[3]6 = Tr_Q^K (a\sqrt[3]2+b\sqrt[3]4+c\sqrt[3]8)= 6c, \textrm{ (this is a typo on the note saying this is $6b$.)}$$
and
$$0 = Tr_Q^K \sqrt[3]{12} = Tr_Q^K (a\sqrt[3]4+b\sqrt[3]8+c\sqrt[3]{16})= 6b.$$

Then we have $a=b=c=0$, so that $\sqrt[3]3 = 0$. This is a contradiction.

Comment: This method works for i.e. $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[p]2)=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[q]3)$? In other words if we had any prime numbers $p$ and $q$ in the roots and not the $3$

Comment: For distinct prime $p, q$, it is obvious because they have degree $p, q$ respectively. For $p=q$, the same method works.

Comment: i.e. if we had this$[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[2]{2},\sqrt[3]{3}):\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[2]{2})]$ how i can show it?

Comment: $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[2]{2},\sqrt[3]{3}):\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[2]{2})] \leq [\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]3):\mathbb{Q}] = 3$, and $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[2]{2},\sqrt[3]{3}):\mathbb{Q}]$ must have a factor $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]3):\mathbb{Q}]=3$. But, $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[2]2):\mathbb{Q}]=2$. So, we must have $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[2]{2},\sqrt[3]{3}):\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[2]{2})] =3$.

Comment: with the way we said can i take that $$\sqrt[3]3=a+b\sqrt(2)$$ for some $a,b \in Q$ and show this with o contradiction?

Comment: For different $p, q$, the way I showed using degree is much easier. In fact, the way with traces, the problem is how you get $\sqrt[3]3\sqrt 2$ has trace $0$. That is not easy if $p\neq q$.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that
$$\sqrt[3]3=a+b\sqrt[3]2+c\sqrt[3]4$$
for some $a,b,c\in\Bbb Q$ and try to get a contradiction.

Comment: First, i will assume that$\sqrt[3]{3} \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$ then we have $$\sqrt[3]3=a+b\sqrt[3]2+c\sqrt[3]4$$ for some $a,b,c\in\Bbb Q$.But how i ill conclude that these $a,b,c \notin Q$?

Comment: from this equation of $a,b,c$?